# How to create file uploader in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I see CI documentation to create an image uploader.
here is my `Controller` :

```
<?php
class Upload extends CI_Controller {
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
}

function index()
{
    $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
}

function do_upload()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '0';
    $config['max_width']  = '0';
    $config['max_height']  = '0';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        echo $this->upload->display_error();
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        return TRUE;
    }
}
}
```

and here is my `View`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="upload/do_upload" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

But when i upload an image it doesn't upload it and     `$this->upload->display_error()` show nothing(my uploads folder which is in my ci root folder also has 777 permision and i'm using wamp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my function named `function do_upload()` to `function somethingelse()` and my problem solved (because i'm calling a built in function)

Answer (score 1):

Two pointers for you:

```
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
```

Check if the file you're using is not exceeding and the file is being uploaded.

```
echo $this->upload->display_errors();
```

See the `display_errors` with an `s`.

**Suggestions:**

In you form's action attribute use a an absolute URL, like:

```
action="<?php echo base_url() ?>upload/do_upload"
```

Inside your function `do_upload()`, do a `print_r($_FILEs)`, to confirm that the file is uploaded correctly with no errors.

Comment: i do whatever you said but nothing changed

Comment: whats your error now then? what does print_r returns?

Comment: i commented all my do_upload and only use print_r in my function and it gives me Array ( [userfile] => Array ( [name] => chest.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\php7295.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 2085 ) ) but when i uncommented my codes it returns to upload_form again and nothing show

Comment: my problem solved i only change the name of do_upload to something else